# How to have a uniform border in a grid of panels in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a custom class `TileView` that extends `JPanel` representing a Scrabble square.

It looks like this:

[image: scrabble board with borders that are not filled]

As you can see the borders are correctly drawn for each tile. However, I want to manipulate the border of the grid, not each tile individually (so the white line should not be there)

When you don't add a border to `TileView`, it looks like this:
[image: Scrabble board with correct grid border]

**However, I want to manipulate the light gray border, how do I do that?**

My current code:

```
 public TileView(Color color, String text) {
    color = new Color(color.getRGB());
    jText = new JLabel(text);
    jText.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    // Add to frame component
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(jText, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    this.setBackground(color);
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2);
    this.setBorder(border);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

`BoardView` is another `JPanel` representing the whole board. It contains all the tiles and has a `GridLayout` of 15 by 15.

```
    public BoardView() {
    tiles = new ArrayList<>();
    setLayout(gridLayout);
    addDefaultTiles(); // initializes tiles with default scrabble layout
    for (TileView tile : tiles)
        this.add(tile);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

I am fairly new to Java Swing but somewhat familiar with Qt (c++). Couldn't find an immediate answer on Google.

Thanks

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the "white lines" are the spaces between the individual tiles.  They will be whatever color the background color of the board `JPanel` is.  If you don't want any space between the tiles, which will make the tile borders appear abnormally large, change the `GridLayout` to have a zero `hgap` and `vgap`.  If you want a different color, set the background color of the board `JPanel`.